# Data type conversion in GNURadio

Tags: string, floating-point, type-conversion, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I'm reading a stream of float digits from an external program to my GNURadio flowchart through "Socket PDU" bloc. However, the latter delivers a stream of strings instead of floats. I tried writting these value to a .txt file and they 'appear' numbers [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ubm2.jpg), however, they're not considered such by the machine. For clarifications, I'm reading floats values from a Java project that I need it to feed in real-time to my GNURadio project. Is there anyway I can convert this stream to floats in my GNURadio project?
OR
Is there a way to read Floats directly from Java to GNURadio?

Any help is appreciated

Thank you[image]

Comment: It's a "socket PDU" block, not "Socket UDP". It doesn't deliver strings, it delivers messages. These messages contain the raw binary data you sent.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Ah I see! I eddited my Q. Is there a way to convert these raw msgs to float or double?